# Append an image to a div

Tags: jquery

I've got the following code that's taking photos from a flickr feed via JSON and I'm trying to append them to a `div` that sits inside another `div`. I can get it to append all the images into one `div` but I would like it to append each image to a separate `div`.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=XXXMYKEYXXX&photoset_id=XXXMYSETXXX&extras=original_format&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i,item){
        var photo = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.originalsecret + '_o.jpg';
        /*var longer = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.originalsecret + '_t.jpg';*/
        $('<div class="slideshow-content">').appendTo("#slideshow-holder");
        $('<img/>').attr({src: photo}).appendTo(".slideshow-content");
    });
});
```

This editor seems to delete tags so the 2 appends are `"div class="slideshow-content"` and an `"img /"` respectively. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the divs containing each image to by dynamically created, or is it just a single div inside `#slideshow-holder`?

Comment: the first $('') is filled w/ <div class="slideshow-content"> and the second is $('') a <img/>. the editor above seems to remove the tags when posting.

Comment: I want the divs w/ the class on them to be dynamically created and populated with an image for every image in the photo set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=XXXMYKEYXXX&photoset_id=XXXMYSETXXX&extras=original_format&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i,item){
        var photo = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.originalsecret + '_o.jpg';
        $('<img />').attr('src',photo).appendTo("#slideshow-holder").wrap('<div class="slideshow content"/>');
    });
});
```

Or, just construct the HTML string before appending...

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=XXXMYKEYXXX&photoset_id=XXXMYSETXXX&extras=original_format&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i,item){
        var photo = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.originalsecret + '_o.jpg';
        $('<div class="slideshow-content"><img src="'+photo+'"/></div>').appendTo("#slideshow-holder");
    });
});
```

Comment: tried this and it just throws the images into the #slideshow-holder div without wrapping the images in the div w/ the class. thanks though

Comment: Doh. Wrap only works if the element has already been added to the dom. Updated to reflect that.

Edit: Also added an alternative.